# Flex tree vertical scroll issue

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I have a flex tree control bound to an xml data from the database. I have item renderers for the tree items. My concern is, when my tree item size is huge, if I scroll using the mouse, it scrolls in 4-5 items at a time. I need it to scroll item by item. When it scrolls 4-5 items at a time, there seems to be a rendering issue as I have overriden lot of properties of treeitemrenderer and also the custom control i have put into the item renderer

Is there any way I can change the scoll size?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the tree's actual scroll bars. With that you can specify the repeatDelay and repeatInterval

```
<mx:Style>
    HScrollBar, VScrollBar {
        repeatDelay: 2000;
        repeatInterval:1000;
    }
</mx:Style>
```